# How do I figure out which motherboard will support my PCIe needs?

Tags: computer-building, pci-express

I'm getting ready to build system #2 because my first go-around didn't seem to work, or I've done something wrong.

I'm attempting to run a Gigabyte Radeon 5700XT GPU in the same system as a BlackMagic Decklink Quad 2 video capture card...and a single M.2 NVMe drive which will have Windows 10 Pro 64-Bit installed.  The processor is a Ryzen 7 3800X 3rd Gen without integrated graphics.

My current motherboard is a Gigabyte Aorus Ultra, which I thought had enough resources, but I'm learning that it doesn't.

If I install the GPU which is a x16 lane card in the first slot, and the M.2 drive in the smallest slot (bottom), I can run windows, no problem.

The moment I install the Decklink Quad 2 into the 2nd slot, I get zero video output *however* windows boots, and the reason I know this is because I can ping the system on the network and I can remote into it using Windows Remote Desktop client.

When I do remote in, there's no sign of the GPU.

I believe I've learned that I'm using up all of my available PCIe lanes.  I've done just about everything I can think of in the BIOS and in positioning the cards in various ways, but there's only ONE configuration that allows the GPU video output to work *while* the Decklink Quad 2 is installed...and that is to have the GPU in slot 1 and the Decklink in the bottom 4x slot.

The problem with this is that the Quad 2 requires 8 lanes, and despite the fact that the BlackMagic drivers see the card when Windows boots in this configuration, I believe it won't see the entire card, and won't operate correctly.

**Question**: What do I need to look for in a Motherboard that will clue me into knowing, with confidence, that the GPU which is x16 and the Decklink Quad 2 which requires x8 will both operate without compromising each other's PCIe resources?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its the processor that handles the pcie lanes, not the motherboard. Study processor specs to learn more.

Comment: You have no video because you are likely using a PCIe slot that is disabled when an NVMe drive is being used.  The solution is to verify this is the case, what PCIe slots are disabled when an M.2 slot is used, should be documented by the manual for the motherboard.